# Project a Column from a Swift Array of Tuple

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, tuples

I have a Swift array of tuples, `Persons = [(name:String, age:Int)]`.
Now I would like to extract all distinct names in an array of String, `name:[String]` from `Persons` array. How can I get it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You could map the array to only extract the `"name"` and then put the result in a set.

Comment: I don't know how to use map. I think there might be a direct way to do it. I am just wondering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let distinctNames = Set(Persons.map { $0.name })
```

Answer (score 3):

Small code example for you how to use `map` function:

```
struct Person {
        let name: String
        let age: Int
}

let people = [
    Person(name: "Oleg",  age: 24),
    Person(name: "Igor",    age: 26),
]

let names: [String] = people.map { return $0.name }
```

Comment: As i could notice question is with Swift tag.

Comment: i know..but i am new to swift

Comment: This is a nice example for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127638/nsarray-equivalent-of-map

Comment: Actually the OP should use the struct at once rather than the tuple ;-)